# Equivalence relation on a set

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I need to find the smallest equivalence relation on the following set: $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ that contains the relation $\{(a,b),(a,c),(d,e)\}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that we have some strict policy that must be followed to be a part of this wonderful site. First, you don't throw questions at someone's face and ask them to solve it for you. It's not a homework help site. Show, where you got stuck, people will definitely assist you. For more info refer here-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960 .Hope you have a better experience here next time. Hope to get you back as a more responsible member. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of how I would approach the problem.

Let $R$ be the smallest such equivalence relation. Then $R$ must contain the three pairs you listed but $R$ must also be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Reflexive means that $(x,x) \in R$ for every $x \in \{a,b,c,d,e\}$. This gives 5 pairs that we need to add to $R$.

Symmetric means that whenever $(x,y) \in R$, $(y,x)$ is also in $R$. This gives us three more pairs to add to $R$.

Transitive means that if $(x,y),(y,z) \in R$, then $(x,z) \in R$.  To fulfill this condition we need to add two more pairs to $R$.

Once you have done that, it is time to check that $R$ is indeed an equivalence relation. Next you should check that if you removed any of the pairs i  $R$ would no longer be an equivalence relation and hence $R$ is the smallest such equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

How about $a\equiv b\equiv c$ and $d\equiv e$?

So that you get $2$ classes:  $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{d,e\}$.

Note that then $a\equiv b$, $a\equiv c$ and $d\equiv e$ as required.   About the only thing we need additionally is that $b\equiv c$ (this follows from transitivity, since $a$ is equivalent to both...).

Comment: May you expand on this? It reads so simply but its 'too' simple for me to grasp as is

Comment: @JamesKelly well, I'll try...  see an equivalence relation _partitions_  the set...  into _residue classes_ (or _congruence classes_)

Comment: @JamesKelly  elements that are equivalent are in the same class...

Comment: @JamesKelly and vice versa...